# Android Mapsforge 3 - creating bitmap from map.

Tags: java, android, bitmap

The method:

```
mapView.takeScreenshot(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, new File (path));
```

works ok, but...
I want to create bitmap without clicking on any button (after loading map ). 
In onCreate method (in my class which extends MapActivity) I'm trying to create bitmap. In file .png I see empty area.

In my opinion I should wait to finish loading map but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas... ?

Comment: create new thread, sleep that for a few second and call your method in the thread

Comment: But how many seconds ? In Xperia J - 10, in Samsung GN - 1 ? In my opinion it's bad solution.

Comment: if you have `OnResume()` method put in last line and if you don't have that put your thread in last line of `OnCreate()` method. and sleep thread just for 1 second.

Comment: But my map loading asynchronously. OnCreate has finished , but the map loading doesn't.

Comment: when map loading finished? how you load map?post some code

Comment: This is my onCreate method: 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.maps_layout);

         mapView = (CustomMapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
         
         File fileMap = new File(mapPath);
         mapView.setMapFile(fileMap);  

    }

And when map loading finished ? I don't know. Loading = draw on the screen.